# Can't restrict API key access when making Ajax requests to Google TIme Zone API

Tags: ajax, time, zone

I'm making requests to [Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro) using Ajax and by following [this tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/local-time-google-time-zone-api.shtml):

```
var apicall = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&key=YOUR_API_KEY'

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() // create new XMLHttpRequest2 object
xhr.open('GET', apicall) // open GET request
xhr.onload = function(){
    if (xhr.status === 200){ // if Ajax request successful
        var output = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) // convert returned JSON string to JSON object
        console.log(output.status) // log API return status for debugging purposes
        if (output.status == 'OK'){ // if API reports everything was returned successfully
                    // do something
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status)
    }
}
xhr.send() // send request
```

I've replaced the key parameter with my generated API Key in Google Console, and the request works. The problem is I can't seem to restrict the API key access by either Referrer or Server IP in Google Console- specifying the domain of my server or IP doesn't work. My guess is Ajax doesn't send referrer or server IP info along with the request for Google to determine if it's a valid request? At the moment I'm stuck with using **no** API key restrictions, though this is not a good idea of course.

Anyone have any experience restricting Google API key access when making calls to Google APIs via AJax?

Answer (score 0):

just remind, just do not embed API keys directly in code

[google api](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037)